# input[type="text"] element cannot display as inline but inline-block

Tags: html, css, forms, inline-styles

As the title described, I can't set the style of a `input[type="text"]` element to `display: inline`.

After I apply the styles, it still behaves like `display: inline-block`

I tried the codes below.

```css
.box {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px;
}

.inline {
  border: 2px solid rebeccapurple;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <input class="inline" type="text" name="" id="" value="input">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <span class="inline">span</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Display on Edge:

[image: Edge performance]

Display on Chrome:

[image: Chrome performance]

I google this question but get nothing.

I've check the dev tools (in Edge), it shows the `input[type="text"]` element actually has the `display: inline` property as its style.

[image: Edge Dev Tools]

but it just display as a `inline-block` element, and not behaved like the span (which behaved like a `inline` element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input>` is a special element. In some cases they are considered as "replaced element" and in other cases, their display is always `inline-block` even if you explicitly change it. In all the cases, an `<input>` will behave as `inline-block` and never as an `inline`

Below is the computed value of display. In your case, it's inline-block even if inline is specified

[image]